# Azure DevOps Integrations in Postman are not working

Tags: azure-devops, postman

I am using the latest [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) version v10.14.9, where I am trying to connect the API to the [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) repository, but I am unable to see the organization name after successful authorization.

I performed the following steps:

1. Select the API and try 'Connect Repository' button.

   [Connect Azure DevOps Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ODZ8.png)
2. After clicking on Azure DevOps, get redirected to authorize my account

   [Authorize azure account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcZF8.png)
3. After clicking on the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button, I get redirected to the callback page which is a success

   [User account authorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4HOF.png)
4. Back to the Postman application, when selecting the 'Azure DevOps organization' drop down, unable to see the organization name and therefore can't connect to the repository.

   [Organization name missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVYDa.png)

Additional details in Azure DevOps:

1. Third-party access is enabled in Azure DevOps

   [Azure third-party access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ISXB.png)

Background information:

In Postman, initially when working on this project, I was using Postman v9 and was able to connect to the Azure DevOps repository and commit the API related changes. But in April, I was forced to update Postman to the latest version as I noticed that I was unable to commit the changes. After updating Postman app to the latest version since then I am unable to see the organization name while trying to connect to the repository. I even tried downgrading Postman to the older version but still facing the same issue.

In Azure DevOps, I created a new internal organization (not related to the client's project) and was able to see the organization name while trying to connect to the repository in Postman. I compared the details of both these organizations (internal one and the client's), but I could not find any major difference.